# Why do I need to set a timezone for my server, but not using Unix Timestamp?

Tags: server, timezone, unix-timestamp, datetimeoffset

I am a newbie to backend and creating a backend server that handles multiple countries' data.

Some countries have a daylight saving issue that requires us to correct timezones twice a year regarding their local data, which would make more work on the server, I think.

I know Unix timestamp is the same everywhere so
Is it easier for us to use the Unix timestamp for all data from anywhere rather than UTC+0 ?

Comment: Unix timestamps are already in UTC. Whether you call that UTC or UTC+0 doesn't matter. Generally speaking, the timezone of your server doesn't matter either. So, what specifically is your question?

Comment: Hi Matt, Sorry if I did not make my question clear.

Comment: I am making a schedule server to send me my Todo tasks to my web app everyday at 8.00 am. Because I work in 3 countries with different timezones so I think whether I need to setup a specific timezone for my server.

Comment: The time zone of your server should be irrelevant to such tasks.  In most cases a server's time zone should be set to UTC, but it could be set to anything - so you should design your application to not be affected by it.  How to do that greatly depends on exactly the technologies you're using and the code you write - which you've not specified at all here.  [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897258/634824).  Also please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because this one really doesn't fit the minimal guidelines.  Thanks.